# Why can't I import from sibling folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Still a bit new to making a application from scratch with python.  Here is my file structure

```
Sudoku
  |--__init__.py
  |--game.py
  |--__pycache__
  |--components
      |---__init__py.
      |--board.py
      |__pycache__(not sure how this got here?)
  |--gui
      |--__init__.py
      |--gui.kv
  |--solver
      |--__init__.py
      |--mysolver.py
```

I have a working Sudou game with my componets and gui modules being utilized in my `game.py`.  Now I am trying to write a sudoku solver that uses that inherits the `Board` class I have (since it has some useful methods and has the board data).

In my `solver.mysolver.py`, I have tried
`from components.board import Board` which says "No module named components" which makes sense since they're not on the same level.

When I try `from .components.board import Board` which I thought would work I get `attempted relative import with no known parent package`.  How can I let all my packages "know" what their parent package is?  All my `__init__.py` files are empty-  should they not be?  Also is there something wrong with my structure - I got a `__pycache__` in my `components` folder and I don't know why.  I was testing my `board.py` inside the components folder directly for a while - is that what created this?

Comment: How are trying to import those folders, can you show some import lines

Answer (score 1):

Imports from outside of tree your current folder is the root of are tricky. To import from the parent folder or a sibling try starting your imports with:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

This will add the parent folder to the path list of folders to look for modules in making your siblings visible. It is kind of gross, but it works for me as a quick fix.

When I first started using python I also ran into this layout issue. The temptation to want to have a runnable script like your solver that utilized all the same code. Python does not really want us to layout like this.

You would probably find it easer to work with things in general if mysolver.py was in the root folder with game.py.

Comment: Ah that does work, and yes it is a bit ugly.  So the "right" or "pythonic" way is to just have all my py files inside of my parent `Sudoku` folder?

Comment: The other alternative might be to create a package based on your common code, then you could install it and use it more in the way you want to. Though I know that might not be ideal during active development.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I want to import the from board.py, my import statement in game.py will be like

```
from components.board import <my_class_name>
```

**pycache** is the complied pyhton classes

```
Sudoku
  |--__init__.py
  |--game.py
  |--__pycache__
  |--components
      |---__init__py.
      |--board.py
      |__pycache__(not sure how this got here?)
  |--gui
      |--__init__.py
      |--gui.kv
  |--solver
      |--__init__.py
      |--mysolver.py
```

Comment: This gives me a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'components'` when I try `from components.board import Board`